# Multiple KVM Whonix-Workstations

Tags: networking, kvm, tor, whonix

I've read about [multiple Whonix-Workstations](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Multiple_Whonix-Workstations) and would like to clarify.

Is it correct that:

1. If I want one Whonix-Gateway and multiple Whonix-Workstations in KVM I just need to edit Whonix-Workstation's `/etc/network/interfaces.d/30_non-qubes-whonix` file by changing the last octet of the IP address (e.g. `10.152.152.11` to `10.152.152.12` if it's the second Workstation or `10.152.152.11` to `10.152.152.13` if it's the third Workstation, etc.)?
2. If I want to add another Workstation and want to use separate Gateway for that Workstation in KVM I need to create new internal network by changing the name attribute in Whonix's network XML file (e.g. `Whonix` to `Whonix2` if it's the second Gateway or `Whonix` to `Whonix3` if it's the third Gateway, etc.) and accordingly change the line `<source network='Whonix'/>` in both Gateway's and Workstation's XML files? And if it's the first Workstation for that Gateway (but not the first Workstation on the host) there is no need to change the IP address as in the first paragraph because we created network (e.g. `Whonix2`, `Whonix3`, etc.) that's completely separate and independent from previously created networks? And generally IP addressess of different networks in KVM are completely independent (e.g. we can have one Gateway with `Whonix` network name and three Workstations using that Gateway with IP addresses `10.152.152.11`, `10.152.152.12`, `10.152.152.13` and at the same time another Gateway with `Whonix2` network name and three Workstations using that Gateway with the same IP addresses (`10.152.152.11`, `10.152.152.12`, `10.152.152.13`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you understand perfectly how it works. I'm happy that my documentation gets the point across. ^HU (KVM maintainer)